# I am not able to stop a small file download with chrome.downdloads API in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to stop before ending (and restarting it after some analysis) files downloads in Chrome extension manifest version 3. I am using chrome.downloads.OnDeterminingFileName and chrome.downloads.OnCreated event to detect when a download starts and then the first thing my code does inside that event handler is using chrome.downloads.pause method to stop that download.
ADITION:

```
        chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (downloadItem) {
        
        if(downloadItem.fileSize < 20971520 && downloadItem.filename.endsWith('.exe') ){

        chrome.downloads.pause(downloadItem.id);
        console.log(downloadItem.id)

        }
});
```

The problem is that it is not working with small files (smaller than 1MB) because it is being downloaded. With bigger ones it is working nicely. Could I do anything to fix this? Can I avoid this behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, I just added my code. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I've reread your question, and it sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. Can you tell us more about the "analysis" you're performing, and why you're performing it?

Comment: If anyone is interested in having a solution to this problem, support this ticket on Chrominium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1458828#c3

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem, but I don't have a solution.

[chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#event-onDeterminingFilename)

```
If the listener calls suggest asynchronously, then it must return true.
The DownloadItem will not complete until all listeners have called suggest.
```

Therefore, the following code should automatically pause all downloads.

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Pause Downloads",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "action": {
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```js
function onChanged(downloadDelta) {
    console.log("onChanged", downloadDelta);
}

function onCreated(downloadItem) {
    console.log("onCreated", downloadItem);
}

function onDeterminingFilename(downloadItem, suggest) {
    console.log("onDeterminingFilename", downloadItem, suggest);
    
    chrome.downloads.pause(downloadItem.id)
    .then(function() {
        suggest();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("background.js", "onDeterminingFilename", error);
        suggest();
    });
    return true;
}

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(onChanged);
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(onCreated);
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(onDeterminingFilename);
```

I used https://fastest.fish/test-files to test downloads with different file sizes.

But it's like you said, the extension only pauses downloads >= 1 MB.

When I download a 1 KB file, the extension logs:

1. onCreated: state = in_progress
2. onDeterminingFilename: state = in_progress
3. onChanged: paused = true
4. onChanged: fileSize = 1000
5. onChanged: state = complete

In other words: The extension pauses the download, but Chrome ignores this and finishes the download anyway.

If nobody else has a solution, you should probably report this as a bug, and link to the bug report in your question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue for a plugin I'm writing. Small files finish despite pause.

Answer (score 0):

[@Thomas Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76004965/12657925) sounds right.However, just to add, unlike chrome, I tried to pause download of multiple files even for a file of size 1 byte. Firefox, seems working well in all cases.

```js
function onPaused(downloadId) {
    console.log(`Paused download`);
    const myTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        let resuming = browser.downloads.resume(downloadId)
        resuming.then( (res) => {
            console.log({ res })
        }, (err) => console.error( err ) )

    }, 3000);
}
  
function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}
  
// DETECTING DOWNLOAD 
function handleCreated(downloadItem) {
    const downloadId = downloadItem?.id
    
    let pausing = browser.downloads.pause(downloadId);
    pausing.then(() => onPaused(downloadId) , onError);
}
browser.downloads.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```